# How to extract value from css with Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

How can I extract "2015-06-18 15:24:48" from this code with JSoup?

```
<span class="review-time">Added <time datetime="2015-06-18 15:24:48">6 months ago</time></span>
```

I'm only able to extract "Added 6 months ago" by code below, but it's not what I need.

```
String date = element.getElementsByClass("review-time").text();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already selected `<span class="review-time">...</span>` part now you can simply select `<time..>` element and read its `datetime` attribute. So your code can look like:

```
String date = element.getElementsByClass("review-time").select("time").attr("datetime");
```

Or you could even simplify it a little with one CSS selector like:

```
String date = element.select("span.review-time time").attr("datetime")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as shown below. What you have to do is create a Document that stores the parsed html using Jsoup and then use the Document's select method to find the tag which is `<time>` and select its `datetime` attribute and print it.

```
String s = "<span class=\"review-time\">Added <time datetime=\"2015-06-18 15:24:48\">6 months ago</time></span>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s);
Element timeTag = doc.select("time").first();

String dateTimeAttr= timeTag.attr("datetime");

System.out.println(dateTimeAttr);
```